# Error reading character of string - visual studio 2017

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the strtok function, which shows results as program targets, but when I set the breakpoints I get an error reading "character reading character of string ..." as in the image. Please explain to me why the error occurred and how to fix 
[image]
Thank you very much
here, all my code

Comment: Please add your code as text, as a code snippet. It's always better to submit text as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: According to the current location, neither `token` nor `next_token` was declared yet.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I posted a question on stackoverflow :D

Comment: @timrau I don't  understand what you mean, can you tell me more clearly? thank you very much

Comment: Go ahead several more steps by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> and see how they change.

Answer (score 0):

In the screen-shot `next_token` is clearly an invalid pointer; the memory does not exist in the process's virtual memory map, so the data cannot be displayed.

This is entirely expected, and ***not an error*** - the breakpoint is set to *before* the pointer is initialised.  If you let it run to line 20, (the next breakpoint) it will be assigned a valid value, and the debugger will display the data normally.

Was it your intention to include the whitespace in the extracted tokens, or should `s` perhaps be `" -"` or even `" \t-"`?

The message in the debugger simply means that the pointer is invalid; it is not an error in your code unless and until you attempt to deference it, which you do not do until after it is valid.